# Ajax Call to Service with Multiple Return Values

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am building a WCF service in C# in which I would like to be able to return multiple values from some of my functions. The code below appears to do this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void ReturnMultipleValues(int startingValue)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var jsonData = new { FirstValue = startingValue, SecondValue = startingValue * 2 };

    Context.Response.Write(ser.Serialize(jsonData));
}
```

I am trying to access this function through an ajax call in JavaScript code:

```
function runTestService() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:12345/WebServices/MyService.asmx/ReturnMultipleValues",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ 'startingValue' : 6 }",
        dataType: "json",
        done: function(data) {
            var firstValue = data.FirstValue;
            var secondValue = data.SecondValue;
            alert("First: " + firstValue + ", Second: " + secondValue);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

When I execute the above JavaScript code, the function in the `.done` portion never executes. When I check Fiddler, however, I see that the function in my service did execute properly and returned the correct values in the JSON.

Is there another way I should code either the service or the ajax call to it?

Comment: Check your console for any errors.

Comment: Add an error handler and see what the error is....

Comment: Without knowing the error, it's challenging. I suspect the return header may not be set to JSON, which may be throwing off the AJAX call. As others have stated, add an error handler to the AJAX call to catch what error is really causing the problem.

Comment: I have added a handler for the error. I have edited the code in my post to include it. I do get an error message: (SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 33). I took a look at the Raw view of the result in Fiddler. It did not return correctly formed JSON: {"FirstValue":6,"SecondValue":12}{"d":null}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to write to `Context.Response` by yourself. Just return an object from method and let the framework do it for you

```
[WebMethod]
public object ReturnMultipleValues(int startingValue)
{
    var jsonData = new { FirstValue = startingValue, SecondValue = startingValue * 2 };
    return jsonData;
}
```

And you have to consider the fact web service wraps json repsonse in object with `d` property

```
{
    "d": {
        "FirstValue": 6,
        "SecondValue": 12
    }
}
```

So update js as well

```
done(function (data) {
    data = data.d;
    var firstValue = data.FirstValue;
    var secondValue = data.SecondValue;
    alert("First: " + firstValue + ", Second: " + secondValue);
});
```

Comment: I modified my service to work like this. It now works the way I wanted. Thanks.